# CSS paragraph indenting next to an aside block

Tags: html, css

I am creating a html page with floating images left and right. I also have special paragraphs that should be indented, not only the first line, but the whole paragraph.

This indenting works, but not at the right side of a left floating image.

I created CSS instructions for this type of paragraph with `margin-left: 50px;`

As said, this works. But not next to a left side image.

I created a sample html page that demonstrates the problem:

```css
p {
  max-width: 500px; 
}
.indent {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.normal {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.left-side {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="normal">
  A normal paragraph
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words.
</p>
<p class="indent">
  An indent paragraph
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words.
</p>
<aside class="left-side"></aside>
<p class="normal">
  A normal paragraph
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words.
</p>
<p class="indent">
  An indent paragraph
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words.
</p>
<p class="normal">
  A normal paragraph
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words
  with lots of words.
</p>
```

I now can see that the paragraph block extends from the left side of the page, but that the paragraph text extends from the right side of the image. To show this, I colored the backgrounds.

I was expecting that indenting would also happening at the right side of the images.

Since I am having a mix of normal and to be indented paragraphs, the trigger to indent must somehow lie in the paragraph, not in the floating left element. Therefore, right-padding of that floating element will not be a solution, because then all paragraphs will be indented.

Some paragraphs will only be partially next to the floating left image. Maybe this complicates matters?

I already noticed that the background area that the paragraphs occupy is not the same as the text area of these same paragraphs. Can this phenomenon perhaps lead to some solution?

What I want to achieve may not be possible. In that case can someone please explain why.

Comment: Using `margin-right` on the floating image will help, but then it will indent even the normal paragraph - but if you want it indented there, I'm guessing you wouldn't use the normal paragraph.

Comment: No, my problem is not solved. As David already remarked, margin-right will also affect the normal paragraphs. There will be a mix of normal and indented paragraphs, partially or complete next to the left floationg element. The suggested duplicates work with margin-right or padding-right. My problem is not solved. If, what I ask, is impossible, then please explain. Piet Blok